# WordPress Themes and PHP unit

Tags: php, theme-development, unit-tests

Is there any examples of using PHP unit tests with WordPress themes, seems a lot of blogs out there on the subject are out dated as the core unit tests are apart of trac, yet last night - I pulled trac and tried to set up a sample theme to run tests on. It doesn't quiet work, you have to run all the tests to test your theme and even if you try and require a file - it tries to require it before WordPress is instantiated and it becomes a giant mess.

Any ways, I know there's the plugin for theme unit testing - but that just installs a ton of posts that "try" and break your theme - doesn't test the underlying logic - especially if building a framework - php unit is best here as you can test out all the different options and implementations of your code.

So is there any way to run PHPunit inside a theme?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it comes to unit testing themes, it's a small jungle. I read on Make WordPress Core that things are changing (http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/08/06/a-new-frontier-for-core-development/).

I searched for blogs linking to that specific post in hope to find some useful. Found this: http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/84669/how-to-add-unit-testing-and-continuous-integration-to-your-wordpress-plugin that looks promising. Note that it focuses on plugin testing, but useful for theme unit testing also.

I'm gonna set up a specific enviroment this week (if nothing comes in between) and do a hands on tutorial for Unit testing themes (gonna try different methods).

Slightly off topic (or as a bonus), when i test themes, the tools i use for testing are the following:

**All plugins are listed on the WordPress.org Plugin Repo.**

- **Developer** (Set of tools for developers. When activating the plugin, you will be promted for what kind of development you are working on and a list of installable recomended plugins.)
- **Debug Bar** (Developer Recomended plugin)
- **Debug Bar Extender** (Developer Recomended plugin)
- **Rewrite Rules Inspector** (Developer Recomended plugin)
- **Log Deprecated Notices** (Developer Recomended plugin. **This one i use a lot!**)
- **Regenerate Thumbnails** (Developer Recomended plugin)
- **Theme Check** (Developer Recomended plugin. **This one i use a lot!**)
- **ThemeForest-Check** (While i don't sell things at that place, the theme check is pretty good to my surprise. Note. You need Theme Check Plugin installed)
- **Theme Mentor** (Getting deeper into the code analysis of the themes).